Multi Tenancy in django with user custom domains
I have a project that is currently running with an app called knowledgebase.
In Knowledgebase, users can log in and see the articles created by other users in their company. There are 2 types of articles, public and private articles. Public articles can be accessed by anyone, whether logged in or not.
All public articles are currently found in a public knowledgebase which is basically a page on a route like /articles/public/company-1 which shows all public articles by company 1 and we may have another like /articles/public/company-2 which shows public articles by company 2 and so on. We are currently thinking of adding custom user domains to the project such that company 1 can add a domain like company1.com which will basically return similar view as /articles/public/company-1. Company 2 can also add company2.com and return their public articles too.
How can we achieve this? Additional info: The frontend is written in react and the backend is running on django-rest-framework. The apps are hosted separately in heroku and domains are from cloudflare. NOTE: we are open to any solutions, even if making the public articles a separate project.
I have tried checking out projects like django-tenants but still not sure of how the approach would be especially on deployment and what happens when a user adds a new domain, its ownership verification and updating related config files to set it up correctly.

are you find sites framework??
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/sites/#associating-content-with-multiple-sites
